# Regarding Covid-2 Spike Antibody Test

Tags: sars-cov-2

Is the data regarding the level ranges and their respective interpretations for different covid antibody level tests available online?

Let's say a person X wants to interpret the results of his Covid Antibody Test report and he finds the interpretation given in the report to be very ambiguous.

So for instance, in his report the interpretation is given as:

```
< 0.8 U/mL = Non-Reactive,

> 0.8 U/mL = Reactive

Linear Range = 0.4 to 250 U/mL
```

while X's test result is:

```
SARS CoV-2S Antibody Levels                                      2610 U/mL
(One Step Double Antigen Sandwich Assay by ECLIA )
```

X wants to know whether his body has developed sufficient antibodies from the two vaccine shots he has got. But the number given above in units unknown to him along with a confusing interpretation has not helped him.

How can he interpret antibody level test results in an Elecsys Anti-SARS CoV 2 S test such as the one given above?

Comment: Antibody tests are not recommended for determining an individual's level of vaccine protection.

Comment: Then they are basically useless?

Comment: For non-vaccinated people they have been useful to identify people previously infected. But you're correct, they are not useful for the purpose you want to use it for.

Comment: Thanks. That's all I needed to know. Is there a test recommended for determining an individual's level of vaccine protection?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

[This fact sheet](https://www.fda.gov/media/144035/download) on the Elecsys Anti-SARS-CoV-2 S test from Roche, the test manufacturer, has useful information.

In particular it notes:

> You should not interpret the results of this test as an indication or
> degree of immunity or protection from infection.

Comment: That means the test is basically useless?